# SQL Problem | how to find the authors Who wrote most fantasy Books

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I cant figure It out how to find the authors Who wrote most fantasy Books.

### Problem

Considering

```
Book(IdBook(PK),Title,Genre,IdAuthor,Price)
Author(Id,Name,Surname)
```

### Example

```
James Lone wrote 13 fantasy Books
Chase Los wrote 28 fantasy Books
Jane Mitchell wrote 27 fantasy Books
Adam John wrote 28 fantasy Books
```

I Need name and Surname of Adam and Chase, because they wrote the most Books among all the authors.

Consider that I'm looking for a generic answer or at least a way to guide me, there's no a specific DBMS. Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output and how to determine more fantasy book? Shoul be more than 50% of authors all book?

Comment: It was an exam, there were no data, Just the schema. The request was the authors Who wrote the most Books among all the authors, i Hope It makes sense for you
For example
Author A wrote 13 Books
Author B wrote 26 Books and Author C wrote 26 , Author D Wrote 11Books, I Need to show name and Surname of author B and C, because they wrote the most Books among all authors

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, Have a look here => [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use analytical functions as Popeye shown. If you are to solve it without analytical functions, the query become little bit more verbose (and without `with` clause even more). Anyway this could be solution safe for "paper RDBMS":

```sql
with counts as (
  select IdAuthor, count(*) as cnt
  from book
  where Genre = 'fantasy'
  group by IdAuthor
)
select Name, Surname
from Author
where Id in (
  select IdAuthor from counts where cnt = (select max(cnt) from counts)
)
```

Comment: Can I Create a View and put all the things that you wrote in counts?

Comment: Yes, you can. The definition of view is exactly as what is in `with counts as ( ... )` parenthesis.

Comment: @malak2206 You are welcome. It is not mandatory but on StackOverflow it's kind of politeness to accept answer to mark question solved.

Comment: I Think I accepted this answer. I'm new on stockverflow! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select name from
(Select a.name, dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
  From author a join book b 
    On a.id = b.author_id
 Group by a.id, a.name) t
Where rn = 1
```

Another way is to achieve using row limiting clause but it depends on database that you are using.

In oracle, you can use the fetch clause as follows:

```
Select a.name, count(*) num_of_books
  From author a join book b 
    On a.id = b.author_id
 Group by a.id, a.name
 Order by count(*) desc
 Fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I had to Say Who wrote the most Brooks, I wrote and example above, im not a native speaker, Sorry...

Comment: What does danse rank do? I've never seen a query made like this in lectures, maybe my professor wouldnt enjoy It! Are there any other easier solution?

Comment: Let me know the database that you are using

Comment: @malak2206 I'm pretty sure if you describe your intention precisely and dense_rank will fit on it, professor will enjoy it. Your question is worded very poorly - I don't mean you are not native speaker (neither I am) but rather not mentioning RDBMS, vague description, missing pretty formatting etc. Correct it and you won't receive downvotes or closing votes. If you don't have sample data, design your own.

Comment: Im not using anydatabase, you must consider this was an exam , and we have to write the query on a paper, so we must use generic functions that all dbms might support( for example no except because there are Just few DBMS that support this function)

Comment: Tomas thank you for the tip, I've edited the post

Comment: Thank you Popeye for the help